# When best to remove an observer from a property when using a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uicollectionviewcell

In my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, I set the model and then observe a property on the model using KVO. I'm just not sure when the best place to remove the observer is.

I could remove it when the model is changed, but that means the observer will still be active when the cell is removed from the screen and put in the reuse queue. Similarly with `-prepareForReuse`

Is there a better place to put it than `-viewWillMoveToSuperview:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know how I hadn't noticed it before, but the answer is to use `-collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` on the UICollectionViewDelegate.